# Read and write global variable

Tags: angular, variables, components, global

I read a router param in my MainComponent in this way:

```
  ngOnInit(){
      this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
         const id = params['id'];
         console.log(id);
     });
 }
```

I need to read "id" in another component (ContactComponent) that is no related to MainComponent, here's my routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'contatti', component: ContattiComponent },
{ path: 'main/:id', component: MainComponent}
  ];
```

my idea was to store "id" in a global variable and then read in ContactComponent that global variable.
I have no idea on how to do so.

Comment: Service is one of the way to store the value in one place and access it globally.

Comment: check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44414226/angular-4-pass-data-between-2-not-related-components

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing data from one typescript file to another in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57956854/passing-data-from-one-typescript-file-to-another-in-angular)

Comment: @Francesco what's your use case? If you need to access the `id` param from the URL, you probably should have it in there. If you open `ContattiComponent` directly, without opening the `MainComponent`, there would be no `id`, regardless of how you store it